Is there a way to put cells of a notebook in raw mode, when using the notebook with VSCode?
I'm writing a notebook in VS Code for my experiments and have some cells in it that I don't need to run every time, I would like a way to mark them as hidden or inactive.
The options I found are:

Put them in raw mode - VS Code doesn't seem to have that option available, I only see code and markdown.

Use the directive %%script false --no-raise-error - this apparently works in Jupyter notebooks, but it doesn't work in VS Code, it fails saying there is no program called false.


I know that commenting the code out and adding flags in the code are options, but they're not as convenient as the above ones. Please let me know if there is anything else I can try.

deleting unnecessary code is good practice. So do it.

"Once you are confident some code is unused, get rid of it. Less code to read and maintain is easier to digest and less error-prone."

I do need those parts of the code sometimes. I just don't need them every time I want to run the whole notebook.

Have you tried to use cell tag? https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/interactive/hiding.html  You could tried to use hide-input tag.

create a separate module with the functions and code that you need (effectively a library). then you can import it as and when needed. Otherwise, it just sounds like clutter...

You can quickly switch between Markdown and Code, effectively disabling the cell.

Press the M key to change the cell to Markdown (if the input part is focused, press ESC first).

Press the Y key to switch back to Code.


This is a simple and fast way to make cells inactive and activate them later.

I have comments that start with a # that are treated as headings in markdown. That messes up the notebook, I would rather prefer it to be treated as raw text.
